# Updating JSESSIONID cookie value

Tags: java, spring, servlets, cookies

I am trying to update the `JSESSIONID` value as below but its creating a new `JSESSIONID` cookie for each request.

```
    Cookie[] cookies = httpRequest.getCookies();
    Cookie jsessionCookie = null;
    Cookie hazelcastCookie = null;
    if (cookies != null) for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        if (cookie.getName().equals(JSESSION_COOKIE_NAME))
            jsessionCookie = cookie;
        else if (cookie.getName().equals(HAZELCAST_COOKIE_NAME)) hazelcastCookie = cookie;
    }
    if (jsessionCookie != null && hazelcastCookie != null
            && jsessionCookie.getValue() != hazelcastCookie.getValue()) {
        jsessionCookie.setValue(hazelcastCookie.getValue());
        httpResponse.addCookie(jsessionCookie);
        LOGGER.log(Level.DEBUG,
                "Updated jsessionCookie value with  hazelcastCookie --> " + jsessionCookie.getValue());
    }
```

What change I should make to just update the `JSESSIONID` value instead of creating a new one for each request?

**UPDATE**

**Request Headers**

```
Accept:text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8
Connection:keep-alive
Cookie:WebDAV.activeX=false; JSESSIONID=HZ9542C5A55A7142A28935DFF96746230F; hazelcast.sessionId=HZ9542C5A55A7142A28935DFF96746230F; JSESSIONID=HZ9542C5A55A7142A28935DFF96746230F; sessionIdForCognos=HZ9542C5A55A7142A28935DFF96746230F; _sd3_session_id=5436c0eebe806f38ca8d1e2867338e00
```

**Response Headers**

```
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Keep-Alive
Content-Encoding:gzip
Content-Language:en-US
Content-Length:6538
Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8
Date:Thu, 14 Apr 2016 22:20:36 GMT
Expires:Wed, 31 Dec 1969 23:59:59 GMT
Keep-Alive:timeout=70, max=57
Pragma:no-cache
Server:None
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=508E10266957BFF95874CEBFECF5FBAF.qa-trunk-n2; Path=/Passport; Secure; HttpOnly
Set-Cookie:hazelcast.sessionId=HZ9542C5A55A7142A28935DFF96746230F; Path=/Passport
Set-Cookie:JSESSIONID=HZ9542C5A55A7142A28935DFF96746230F
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to set the value of an existing cookie, the following fields of the cookie must all be the same:

1. domain
2. path
3. secure
4. http-only
5. name

Comment: Yes, am not touching any of these am just getting the `JSESSIONID` and updating the value

Comment: Can you show us what the cookies look like in the browser?